# Python Multiprocessing Worker/Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a python function that has to run 12 times in total. I have this set up currently to use Pool from the multiprocessing library to run up to all of them in parallel. Typically I run 6 at a time because the function is CPU intensive and running 12 in parallel often causes the program to crash. When we do 6 at a time, the second set of 6 will not begin until all of the first 6 processes are finished. Ideally, we would like another one (e.g. the 7th) to kick off as soon as one from the initial batch of 6 is finished- So that 6 are running at once while there are more to start. Right now the code looks like this (it would be called twice, passing the first 6 elements in one list and then the second 6 in another:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def start_pool(project_list):

    pool = Pool(processes=6)
    pool.map(run_assignments_parallel,project_list[0:6])
```

So i have been trying to implement a worker/queue solution and have run into some issues. I have a worker function that looks like this:

```
def worker(work_queue, done_queue):
    try:
        for proj in iter(work_queue.get, 'STOP'):
            print proj
            run_assignments_parallel(proj)
            done_queue.put('finished ' + proj )
    except Exception, e:        
        done_queue.put("%s failed on %s with: %s" % (current_process().name, proj,        e.message))
    return True
```

And the code to call the worker function is as follows:

```
workers = 6
work_queue = Queue()
done_queue = Queue()  
processes = []
for project in project_list:
    print project
    work_queue.put(project)
for w in xrange(workers):        
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(work_queue, done_queue))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
    work_queue.put('STOP')
for p in processes:
     p.join()    
     done_queue.put('STOP')
for status in iter(done_queue.get, 'STOP'):        
    print status
```

project_list is just a list of paths for the 12 projects that need to be run in the function 'run_assignments_parallel.'

The way this is written now, the function is getting called more than once for the same process (project) and I cant really tell what is going on. This code is based on an example i found and I am pretty sure the looping structure is messed up. Any help would be great and I aplogize for my ignorance on the matter. Thanks!

Comment: Well with the indetation you have you will get errors please check it all

Comment: pxl fixed the obvious format but given that are all the other lines correct - the put('SOP') don't agree with the Python docs example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Ideally, we would like another one (e.g. the 7th) to kick off as soon as one from the initial batch of 6 is finished- So that 6 are running at once while there are more to start.

All you need to change is to pass all 12 input parameters instead of 6:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=6) # run no more than 6 at a time
pool.map(run_assignments_parallel, project_list) # pass full list (12 items)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed correct and something I had tried before and now I realize (again) why my issue is a little more complicated- the function uses an API from some proprietary software that invokes an object that cannot be destroyed and recreated. In other words, each project has to be run on a separate process, which is why the start_pool function gets called again for the second set of 6. Any ideas on how to get around that?

Comment: @user2503169: a) check that the object is already created e.g., make it a global and don't try to recreate it if it is not `None` b) Or if you want a new process for each task: [`maxtasksperchild=1`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) c) Create 12 `Process` and use `Semaphore` to avoid more than 6 running.

Comment: Looks like maxtaskperchild would be an easy solution but I am running 2.6 (because of the proprietary software). Can you tell me how to use Semaphore? I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @user2503169: Create `Semaphore` in the main process with value `6`. Pass it two all child processes (12), wrap your code `with sem: ..your child code here..`. Every time the processing is entered in `with sem` statement, `sem.acquire()` is called automatically that decrements the semaphore value. If it hits zero then `sem.acquire()` blocks until `sem.release()` is called (automatically on the exit from `with sem:`). For example, see how [`RateSemaphore()` is used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16686329/4279) (your case is simpler).

Comment: Like this?: 'maxconnections = 6 sem = BoundedSemaphore(value=maxconnections) with sem: pool = Pool(processes=12) pool.map(run_assignments_parallel,project_list)'

Comment: @user2503169: no. `pool.map` is *not* `your child code` it is executed in the parent. `with sem:` should be inside `run_assignments_parallel`. [Ask new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if it is still unclear.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [MPipe](http://vmlaker.github.io/mpipe) module.

Create a 6-worker, single-stage pipeline and feed in all your projects as *tasks*. Then just read the *results* (in your case, statuses) off the end.

```
from mpipe import Pipeline, OrderedStage

...    

pipe = Pipeline(OrderedStage(run_assignments_parallel), 6)    

for project in project_list:
   pipe.put(project)

pipe.put(None)  # Signal end of input.

for status in pipe.results():
   print(status)
```