# How can I slow queries to API to prevent query cap with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, time, multiprocessing

I'm running into problems with a query cap on the ConceptNet API. I'm downloading a query for each word in a vocabulary list of several thousand words, but the API caps queries at 600 calls per minute. If I were sending the queries from one script, I could simply make a call every 0.1 sec (1 minute/600 calls). However, I am using several processes which query the API simultaneously.

My current approach is to use a `JoinableQueue` to keep track of how many queries have been called. When the queue has 600 elements, I pause execution for one minute.

This doesn't seem like the most time efficient solution, because if the 600 calls take more than 1 minute to complete, the timer for the server has already reset (I assume).

Is there a more time efficient solution to avoid the cap?

Comment: Reposting since I deleted it right before you commented: Could you just send 600 work items in your `multiprocessing.Pool`/`Queue`, then sleep for a minute in the parent? Then after a minute, send 600 more, sleep again, etc? This way you're going to end up sleeping about a minute from the time of the first request before sending in new ones. It's hard to say exactly what the best approach is without knowing exactly how ConceptNet calculates things on their end, though.

Comment: @dano (Then I will also repost my comment. :) ) I like it! I'll try this out.

Comment: @dano On further consideration, I see an issue with this suggestion. The queries will take time to complete. In the worst case, if a small number take >60 sec, the new queries start to pile up in the queue and then all get executed together. But it gives me an idea for an alternative, I can add a query to the queue every 0.1 seconds when ever the queue dips below 600.

Comment: [see how `RatedSemaphore(10)` is used to rate limit requests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16686329/4279) (change the imports from `threading` to `multiprocessing` -- otherwise the code should be identical)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think would simply time the execution of each part of the code that makes an API call, and sleep the remainder of 0.1 seconds. I've done something similar to rate-limit output from a test harness, e.g.:

```
for x in xrange(event_count):

    start = time.time()
    yield json.dumps(m.get_mock()) + '\n'
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    time.sleep(max((1 / hits_sec) - elapsed, 0))
```