# Can a generator wrapper be used to rate limit a method call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a method that repeatedly gets called in a loop.

```
for user in users:
     send_email(user)
```

But since I want to reduce congestion, I want something like.

```
for user in rate_limit(per_min=50, users):
     send_email(user)
```

Where the `rate_limit` function simply sleeps and starts yielding from `users` again once the rate limit as been reached.

```
# something like this, where it just sleeps (until next min/sec cycle) 
# once the number of iterations per_min or per_sec have been achieved.

def rate_limit(per_min=None, per_sec=None, objects):
    ...
```

The issue I am facing is that I don't know how to maintain the state (such as the amount of time that has passed or the number of emails sent) in the current form of the method. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or ideas on how to address this problem.

Comment: to avoid unnecessary delays, you could [use `RatedSemaphore(50, 60)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33224087/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I have never seen semaphores used outside multiprocessing/multi-threading situations. Will it work in my situation? Excuse my ignorance

Comment: yes. The first code example in the answer I've linked doesn't create its own new threads (though there is a background thread created by the semaphore, to generate tokens). In your case, it could look like: `for user in users: with rate_limit: send_email(user)`. If `rate_limit = RatedSemaphore(50, 60)` then it guarantees that the loop won't send more than 50 emails per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep):

1. Yield an object
2. Sleep
3. Repeat from step 1

For example:

```
import time

def rate_limit(objects, per_min=None):
    sleep_time = 60 / per_min if per_min else 0
    for obj in objects:
        yield obj
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

---

> Problem is I have no clue how to preserve state (in the sense of time elapsed/emails sent) in this form.

This will automatically preserver the state, as `yield` simply pauses the function and continues after the function is called again. If you want to know the spent time and number of mails sent, you can simply add a counter:

```
def rate_limit(objects, per_min=None):
    sleep_time = 60 / per_min if per_min else 0
    for count, obj in enumerate(objects):
        yield obj
        print('Sent email {0} at {1} seconds.'.format(count, count * sleep_time))
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ill just follow your example

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) this will suspend the current thread for a given number of seconds.