# Handling tasks that never terminate in python3 asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Sometimes async tasks have no meaningful termination condition - for instance, in the program below, the "rate_limiter" task generates a stream of tokens on a queue, at a fixed rate, forever.

```
import asyncio
import sys

@asyncio.coroutine
def rate_limiter(queue, rate):
    """Push tokens to QUEUE at a rate of RATE per second."""
    delay = 1/rate
    while True:
        yield from asyncio.sleep(delay)
        yield from queue.put(None)

@asyncio.coroutine
def do_work(n, rate):
    for i in range(n):
        yield from rate.get()
        sys.stdout.write("job {}\n".format(i))

def main():
    loop   = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    rate   = asyncio.Queue()
    rltask = loop.create_task(rate_limiter(rate, 10))
    wtask  = loop.create_task(do_work(20, rate))
    loop.run_until_complete(wtask)

main()
```

This program works perfectly *except* that the asyncio library considers it a programming error to just throw away `rltask` when there's nothing left to rate-limit; you get a complaint like

```
...
job 18
job 19
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<rate_limiter() running at rl.py:9>
      wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>>
```

(whether or not in debug mode).

I can kludge around this with, like, an Event that tells the `rate_limiter` coroutine to break out of its loop, but that feels like extra code to no real benefit.  How are you *supposed* to deal with this sort of situation when using asyncio?

**EDIT:** I was unclear: what I am looking for is something like the `daemon` flag on threads: something that makes it so I *don't have to wait for a particular task,* ideally expressed as an annotation on the task itself, or its coroutine.  I would also accept an answer that demonstrates that there is no such mechanism.  I'm already aware of workarounds.

Comment: unrelated: in multithreaded case, a [daemon thread is used to produce tokens (see `RatedSemaphore`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16686329/4279) (it dies on the program exit)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Right, this is the same algorithm, converted to asyncio tasks.  As far as I can tell, asyncio has no equivalent of a daemon thread.

Comment: you could get pending tasks using `asyncio.Task.all_tasks()` and call `cancel()` or call just `rltask.cancel()`and break on `CancelledError` in `rate_limiter()`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That involves roughly the same amount of extra code as an Event.

Comment: `while not stopped.wait(delay)` where `stopped` is `asyncio.Event` can emulate `asyncio.sleep(delay)` + `CancelledError` but it won't emulate a more complex code where you need to cleanup on exit (e.g.,  using `with`-statements though the explicit protocol such as `server.close()`, `server.wait_closed()` would be better if you need a clean shutdown).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian [`asyncio.Event.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event.wait) does not have a timeout parameter (unlike [`threading.Event.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html#threading.Event.wait)).

Comment: yes, but it doesn't matter because there is a generic asyncio wait/wait_for that supports `timeout` parameter and works for any coroutine including asyncio.Event.wait. I remember some functions in earlier API versions accepted `timeout` directly but lost it later in preference of the more general `asyncio.wait`. In other words, you still don't need `asyncio.sleep()` and your coroutine can return immediately as soon as the event is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid *"Task was destroyed but it is pending!"* warning, you could mark a never ending coroutine as finished on exit from the program if you set a dummy result for the corresponding future object:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import asyncio
import itertools
from contextlib import closing, contextmanager


@contextmanager
def finishing(coro_or_future, *, loop=None):
    """Mark a never ending coroutine or future as done on __exit__."""
    fut = asyncio.ensure_future(
        coro_or_future, loop=loop)  # start infinite loop
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        if not fut.cancelled():
            fut.set_result(None)  # mark as finished


async def never_ends():
    for c in itertools.cycle('\|/-'):
        print(c, end='\r', flush=True)
        await asyncio.sleep(.3)


with closing(asyncio.get_event_loop()) as loop, \
     finishing(never_ends(), loop=loop):
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(3))  # do something else
```

It assumes that your coroutine does not require an explicit cleanup before the process exits. In the latter case, define an explicit procedure for the cleanup: provide methods that could be called (e.g., `server.close()`, `server.wait_closed()`), or pass an event (`asyncio.Event`) that a caller should set on shutdown, or raise an exception (such as `CancelledError`).

The benefit of introducing `finishing()` is to detect bugs i.e., you should not ignore the warning unless it is explicitly silenced by the `finishing()` call.

Comment: On Python 3.12.2 (installed via pyenv on Ubuntu 20.04) this fails with `RuntimeError: Task does not support set_result operation` (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66093839/1008142). I don't know how to fix this other than `fut.cancel()` followed by `loop.run_until_complete(fut)`, and catching the `CancelledError` (this replaces the code in the `finally` block of `finishing`).  I wonder if this would be a good example for the asyncio docs?

Comment: @RoryYorke `asyncio` changed a lot since Python 3.5 I would use `asyncio.run(main())` with async def main in modern Python.  For the more local option: TaskGroup to create task + cancel for specific task

Answer (score 1):

`.cancel()` the task and then wait for it be cancelled, catching the `CancelledError` outside:

```
# vim: tabstop=4 expandtab

import asyncio
import sys

@asyncio.coroutine
def rate_limiter(queue, rate):
    """Push tokens to QUEUE at a rate of RATE per second."""
    delay = 1/rate
    while True:
        yield from asyncio.sleep(delay)
        yield from queue.put(None)

@asyncio.coroutine
def do_work(n, rate):
    for i in range(n):
        yield from rate.get()
        sys.stdout.write("job {}\n".format(i))

def main():
    loop   = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    rate   = asyncio.Queue()
    rltask = loop.create_task(rate_limiter(rate, 10))
    wtask  = loop.create_task(do_work(20, rate))
    loop.run_until_complete(wtask)
    rltask.cancel()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(rltask)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        ...
    loop.close()

main()
```

Comment: As I said in the comments on the answer, this involves "extra code to no real benefit," just like using an Event to end the loop.  Are you asserting that there is *no way* to _not have to wait for `rltask`_?

Comment: You already *do not have to wait* for `rltask`. The only problem then is that the `asyncio` Task implementation [logs](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/asyncio/tasks.py#L85) that as an [error](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/asyncio/base_events.py#L1097). You could set the *private* [`Task._log_destroy_pending`](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/asyncio/tasks.py#L45) variable to `False`, or you could override the default exception handler w/ `BaseEventLoop.set_exception_handler` to ignore those messages. Either way, extra code is needed.