# asyncio set_exception fails for a pending task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio


async def task_successful():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(task_successful())
    task.set_exception(ValueError)
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

What I expect is an exception rising from `loop.run_until_complete(task)` or at least `task.exception()` being a `ValueError`.

Instead I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "set_exception.py", line 11, in <module>
    task.set_exception(ValueError)
RuntimeError: Task does not support set_exception operation
```

This is very weird since this task is not `done` when the call is made:

```
<Task pending coro=<task_successful() running at set_exception.py:4>>
```

Also it is not an `InvalidStateError` mentioned at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.set_exception)

Tried Python 3.7.5, 3.9.1.

What is it? A bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You're doing something wrong: `Task` is a subclass of `Future` specifically designed to drive the execution of a coroutine. Task sets its own result and exception based on the behavior of the coroutine, so it's not allowed for outside code to set either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a valid operation on the `Task` instance. See the [Task docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task)

> "A **Future-like** object that runs a Python coroutine"

> "`asyncio.Task` inherits from Future all of its APIs except `Future.set_result()` and `Future.set_exception()`."

Further proof, look at [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/206cbdab16cb054e859597a562e2f6ab35e99766/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L144-L145):

> ```py
> class Task(futures._PyFuture):  # Inherit Python Task implementation
>                                 # from a Python Future implementation.
>     ...
>
>     def set_exception(self, exception):
>         raise RuntimeError('Task does not support set_exception operation')
> ```