# Python: Process file line by line and multiprocessing

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a file with several thousand rows. The format is basically:
`text \t url1, url2, url3`

Now, I have a process to take each row and search for content in the url's mentioned. As going and fetching content will take some time, I want to use multiprocessing to speed up things.

```
import gensim, re, string
import multiprocessing
import bz2
from multiprocessing import Pool
import mwparserfromhell, os, time
import codecs
import multiprocessing as mp
from boilerpipe.extract import Extractor
#from multiprocessing import freeze_support
import WikiExtractor as wikiextractor
from gensim.utils import to_unicode,any2unicode
#from lxml.etree import tounicode
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import izip_longest
def read_file(tot):
    file_to_read=os.getcwd()+"/../wikidata/sequence-url-mapper.txt"
    f_r = open(file_to_read,'r')
    for line in f_r:
        content, urls=line.strip().split("||")
        #print "Content =>", content
        #print "URLs =>", urls
        urls = urls.replace('set([u\'','').replace('\'])','').split(",")
        #print urls
        yield content, urls
    f_r.close()

def aggregate_web_content(urls):
    extracted_content=''
    for url in urls:
        try:
            extractor = Extractor(extractor='ArticleExtractor', url=url)
            retrieved_text = extractor.getText()
            lines = retrieved_text.split('\n')
            if len(lines) <= 5:
                continue
            for line in lines:
                if len(line.strip()) > 10:
                    extracted_content=extracted_content+' '+line.replace('\s+',' ')
            extracted_content = extracted_content +"||"
        except:
            continue
    return extracted_content 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    result_list=[]
    f_seq=codecs.open(os.getcwd()+'/../wikidata/sequence-content-mapper.txt','w')
    k=0
    for content, urllist in read_file(1):
        content = content.replace('\s+',' ')
        ext_content=aggregate_web_content(urllist).encode('utf-8','ignore')
        if len(ext_content.strip()) > 10: 
            f_seq.write(content+"\t"+ext_content+'\n')
            k+=1
        #if k==10:
        #    break
        #
        if k>0 and k%10 == 0:
            print "Done with ", k , " lines.."

        if k == 10000:
            break
    f_seq.close()
```

I am not able to use the pool to process the rows separately in different processes.

Comment: Could you explain the bigger problem you are trying to solve? It looks like you are trying to run some Wikipedia articles and do some processing on them? Also, it looks like you set up the pool but never used it so I'm confused at what you are trying to do. If you could give us the full file including impprts it will be easier to help too. One last thing - you can look at this answer for an implementation doing something similar:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181121/python-very-simple-multithreading-parallel-url-fetching-without-queue

Comment: I am basically trying to get the text from the urls. I will take a look at the link you mentioned. I could not get the pool to work, so just kept it as is. Now I am basically using each row and processing the urls, my question is can i use multiprocessing to process multiple lines at the same time such as processing the urls might be easier and quick. I just changed the code too with the imports.