# Processing Results from futures.ThreadPoolExecutor python

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I am using multi threading method with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor for getting results from 1000 of urls in my Django application, this is working well but one clarification i want is will it be correct to process the data then and there once we receive 1st response and about to recieve 2nd response and so on ?

Saving whole json response from 100 URLS and then processing one by one also looks in-correct. Can some one suggest what would be best way of doing it ?

My Question is related to below discussion.

[A very simple multithreading parallel URL fetching (without queue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181121/a-very-simple-multithreading-parallel-url-fetching-without-queue/54062144?noredirect=1#comment94957735_54062144)